# Split String into smaller Strings by length variable

Tags: c#, .net, algorithm, string

I'd like to break apart a String by a certain length variable.
It needs to bounds check so as not explode when the last section of string is not as long as or longer than the length. Looking for the most succinct (yet understandable) version.

Example:

```
string x = "AAABBBCC";
string[] arr = x.SplitByLength(3);
// arr[0] -> "AAA";
// arr[1] -> "BBB";
// arr[2] -> "CC"
```

Answer (score 74, accepted):

You need to use a loop:

```
public static IEnumerable<string> SplitByLength(this string str, int maxLength) {
    for (int index = 0; index < str.Length; index += maxLength) {
        yield return str.Substring(index, Math.Min(maxLength, str.Length - index));
    }
}
```

Alternative:

```
public static IEnumerable<string> SplitByLength(this string str, int maxLength) {
    int index = 0;
    while(true) {
        if (index + maxLength >= str.Length) {
            yield return str.Substring(index);
            yield break;
        }
        yield return str.Substring(index, maxLength);
        index += maxLength;
    }
}
```

2<sup>nd</sup> alternative: (For those who can't stand `while(true)`)

```
public static IEnumerable<string> SplitByLength(this string str, int maxLength) {
    int index = 0;
    while(index + maxLength < str.Length) {
        yield return str.Substring(index, maxLength);
        index += maxLength;
    }

    yield return str.Substring(index);
}
```

Comment: Right on! I didn't want to limit folks by asking for the IEnumerable version. This rocks.

Comment: Great minds think alike, I guess! (Or more humbly: great minds and mediocre minds sometimes have the same thought?)

Comment: Do not like the While (true) I think that is bad style, unless listening on a port.

Comment: @Mike: That's why I included the first version.

Comment: @Mike: I think run-on sentences with no subject in the first clause are bad style. (Oh snap!)

Comment: ugggghhhhh, I can't believe a +1 for oh snap, do you have an alternate account you vote yourself up. (period) Haven't heard that type of talk since grade school

Comment: @Mike: I was just joking, geez. +1 on a comment is meaningless anyway (and no, I did not +1 myself). I just thought it was a little ridiculous that you'd downvote someone because you didn't like his/her *style*. "It answers the question, and it works perfectly, but... I don't like that style, so I'll downvote it."

Comment: @SLaks: I think in your final example, you meant `<=` instead of `>=`.

Comment: +1 Impressioned for the performance (1st version) compared to what I ve used (till now): `string[] sa = (Regex.Split(s, "(...)")); string[] sa = sa.Where(item => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(item)).ToArray();`

Comment: not that you'd use it intentionally so (usage could potentially be buried within other methods), but pointing out that `maxLength == 0` results in an infinite loop

Comment: Love the first solution with the `yield` - so elegant.

Answer (score 14):

Easy to understand version:

```
string x = "AAABBBCC";
List<string> a = new List<string>();
for (int i = 0; i < x.Length; i += 3)
{
    if((i + 3) < x.Length)
        a.Add(x.Substring(i, 3));
    else
        a.Add(x.Substring(i));
}
```

Though preferably the 3 should be a nice const.

Comment: If the int to split by is larger than the string length, this will not yield any result.

Comment: @JYelton: No, it will still enter the loop and end up in the else statement.

Comment: @JYelton: I think you're mistaken. Are you suggesting there's some way to sneak past an `if`/`else` without triggering *either*?

Comment: Nevermind, I was mistaken. I originally thought that the loop would not execute if the split length was longer than the string length, but the check mechanism is built-in.

Comment: beautiful - thanks.  Much easier to follow than the IEnumerable for some of us newer developers

Answer (score 6):

It's not particularly succinct, but I might use an extension method like this:

```
public static IEnumerable<string> SplitByLength(this string s, int length)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < s.Length; i += length)
    {
        if (i + length <= s.Length)
        {
            yield return s.Substring(i, length);
        }
        else
        {
            yield return s.Substring(i);
        }
    }
}
```

Note that I return an `IEnumerable<string>`, not an array. If you want to convert the result to an array, use `ToArray`:

```
string[] arr = x.SplitByLength(3).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 6):

My solution:

```
public static string[] SplitToChunks(this string source, int maxLength)
{
    return source
        .Where((x, i) => i % maxLength == 0)
        .Select(
            (x, i) => new string(source
                .Skip(i * maxLength)
                .Take(maxLength)
                .ToArray()))
        .ToArray();
}
```

I actually rather use `List<string>` instead of `string[]`.

Answer (score 4):

Here's what I'd do:

```
public static IEnumerable<string> EnumerateByLength(this string text, int length) {
    int index = 0;
    while (index < text.Length) {
        int charCount = Math.Min(length, text.Length - index);
        yield return text.Substring(index, charCount);
        index += length;
    }
}
```

This method would provide deferred execution (which doesn't really matter on an immutable class like `string`, but it's worth noting).

Then if you wanted a method to populate an array for you, you could have:

```
public static string[] SplitByLength(this string text, int length) {
    return text.EnumerateByLength(length).ToArray();
}
```

The reason I would go with the name `EnumerateByLength` rather then `SplitByLength` for the "core" method is that `string.Split` returns a `string[]`, so in my mind there's precedence for methods whose names start with `Split` to return arrays.

That's just me, though.

Comment: I wanted to upvote your use of a separate Inner/Impl method, but then you had to go and spoil it by calling .ToArray() in the outer method.

Comment: @Joel: Ha, but that's what the OP requested! Fine, I'll change it up.

Answer (score 1):

Using [`Batch`](http://code.google.com/p/morelinq/source/browse/trunk/MoreLinq/Batch.cs) from [`MoreLinq`](http://code.google.com/p/morelinq/), on .Net 4.0:

```
public static IEnumerable<string> SplitByLength(this string str, int length)
{
    return str.Batch(length, String.Concat);
}
```

On 3.5 Concat need an array, so we can use `Concat` with `ToArray` or, `new String`:

```
public static IEnumerable<string> SplitByLength(this string str, int length)
{
    return str.Batch(length, chars => new String(chars.ToArray()));
}
```

It may be a bit unintuitive to look at a string as a collection of characters, so string manipulation might be proffered.

Answer (score 1):

UPD: Using some Linq to make it actually succinct

```
static IEnumerable EnumerateByLength(string str, int len)
        {
            Match m = (new Regex(string.Format("^(.{{1,{0}}})*$", len))).Match(str);
            if (m.Groups.Count <= 1)
                return Empty;
            return (from Capture c in m.Groups[1].Captures select c.Value);
        }
```

Initial version:

```
        static string[] Empty = new string [] {};

        static string[] SplitByLength(string str, int len)
        {
            Regex r = new Regex(string.Format("^(.{{1,{0}}})*$",len));
            Match m = r.Match(str);
            if(m.Groups.Count <= 1)
                return Empty;

            string [] result = new string[m.Groups[1].Captures.Count];
            int ix = 0;
            foreach(Capture c in m.Groups[1].Captures)
            {
                result[ix++] = c.Value;
            }
            return result;
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Yet another slight variant (classic but simple and pragmatic):

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        string msg = "AAABBBCC";

        string[] test = msg.SplitByLength(3);            
    }
}

public static class SplitStringByLength
{
    public static string[] SplitByLength(this string inputString, int segmentSize) {
        List<string> segments = new List<string>();

        int wholeSegmentCount = inputString.Length / segmentSize;

        int i;
        for (i = 0; i < wholeSegmentCount; i++) {
            segments.Add(inputString.Substring(i * segmentSize, segmentSize));
        }

        if (inputString.Length % segmentSize != 0) {
            segments.Add(inputString.Substring(i * segmentSize, inputString.Length - i * segmentSize));
        }

        return segments.ToArray();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    private string[] SplitByLength(string s, int d)
    {
        List<string> stringList = new List<string>();
        if (s.Length <= d) stringList.Add(s);
        else
        {
            int x = 0;
            for (; (x + d) < s.Length; x += d)
            {
                stringList.Add(s.Substring(x, d));
            }
            stringList.Add(s.Substring(x));
        }
        return stringList.ToArray();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string s = "AAABBBCCC";
        string[] a = SplitByLenght(s,3);
    }

    private string[] SplitByLenght(string s, int split)
    {
        //Like using List because I can just add to it 
        List<string> list = new List<string>();

                    // Integer Division
        int TimesThroughTheLoop = s.Length/split;


        for (int i = 0; i < TimesThroughTheLoop; i++)
        {
            list.Add(s.Substring(i * split, split));

        }

        // Pickup the end of the string
        if (TimesThroughTheLoop * split != s.Length)
        {
            list.Add(s.Substring(TimesThroughTheLoop * split));
        }

        return list.ToArray();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the strange scenario where I had segmented a string, then rearranged the segments (i.e. reversed) before concatenating them, and then I later needed to reverse the segmentation.  Here's an update to the [accepted answer by @SLaks](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3008775/1037948):

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Split the given string into equally-sized segments (possibly with a 'remainder' if uneven division).  Optionally return the 'remainder' first.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="str">source string</param>
    /// <param name="maxLength">size of each segment (except the remainder, which will be less)</param>
    /// <param name="remainderFirst">if dividing <paramref name="str"/> into segments would result in a chunk smaller than <paramref name="maxLength"/> left at the end, instead take it from the beginning</param>
    /// <returns>list of segments within <paramref name="str"/></returns>
    /// <remarks>Original method at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3008718/split-string-into-smaller-strings-by-length-variable </remarks>
    private static IEnumerable<string> ToSegments(string str, int maxLength, bool remainderFirst = false) {
        // note: `maxLength == 0` would not only not make sense, but would result in an infinite loop
        if(maxLength < 1) throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("maxLength", maxLength, "Should be greater than 0");
        // correct for the infinite loop caused by a nonsensical request of `remainderFirst == true` and no remainder (`maxLength==1` or even division)
        if( remainderFirst && str.Length % maxLength == 0 ) remainderFirst = false;

        var index = 0;
        // note that we want to stop BEFORE we reach the end
        // because if it's exact we'll end up with an
        // empty segment
        while (index + maxLength < str.Length)
        {
            // do we want the 'final chunk' first or at the end?
            if( remainderFirst && index == 0 ) {
                // figure out remainder size
                var remainder = str.Length % maxLength;
                yield return str.Substring(index, remainder);

                index += remainder;
            }
            // normal stepthrough
            else {
                yield return str.Substring(index, maxLength);
                index += maxLength;
            }
        }

        yield return str.Substring(index);
    }//---  fn  ToSegments
```

*(I also corrected a bug in the original `while` version resulting in empty segment if `maxLength==1`)*

Answer (score 0):

### I have a recursive solution:

```
    public List<string> SplitArray(string item, int size)
    {
        if (item.Length <= size) return new List<string> { item };
        var temp = new List<string> { item.Substring(0,size) };
        temp.AddRange(SplitArray(item.Substring(size), size));
        return temp;
    }
```

Thoug, it does not returns a IEnumerable but a List