# How to split a string into multiple strings in c#?

Tags: c#, .net

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Split String into smaller Strings by length variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3008718/split-string-into-smaller-strings-by-length-variable)

I have seen solutions that split strings by a certain character but I wanted to seperate a string every certain amount of characters. Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

its been asked

[Split String into smaller Strings by length variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3008718/split-string-into-smaller-strings-by-length-variable)

Comment: Ok thanks. I'll leave the question as a redirect for others because I couldn't find the question you were refering to.