# Is there a way in C#.NET to break a string into substrings of a fixed length?

Tags: c#, .net, algorithm

What I'm trying to do should be obvious from the following snippet of code.

```
    public static void PrintTable ( string[][] cells )
    {
        // Outputs content in cells matrix like 

        // =========================================
        //  cells[0][0]   | cells[0][1]
        // -----------------------------------------
        //  cells[1][0]   | cells[1][1]
        // -----------------------------------------
        //  cells[2][0]   | cells[2][1]
        //                .
        //                .
        // -----------------------------------------
        //  cells[n-1][0] | cells[n-1][1]
        //  ========================================

        // Each cell must be able to hold at least 1 character inside 
        // 1 space of padding on the left and right

        OutputFormatter.PrintChars('=');
        int colOneWidth = Math.Max(cells.Max(c => c[0].Length) + 2, OutputFormatter._outputMaxLength - 7);
        int colTwoWidth = OutputFormatter._outputMaxLength - colOneWidth - 1;
        foreach ( string[] row in cells )
        {
            string[] colOneParts = ... (get row[0] broken down into pieces of width colOneWidth with 1 space of padding on each side)
            string[] colTwoParts = ... (get row[1] broken down into pieces of width colTwoWidth with 1 space of padding on each side)
            // ... 
        }

        // ... 
        OutputFormatter.PrintChars('=');
    }
```

Does the .NET library have any way of making my life easy for the part where I need to break down a `string` into sub`string`s of a fixed length? This is so I can get stuff on multiple lines, like

```
====================================================
 This is only on 1 line | As you can see, this is o
                        | n multiple lines.
----------------------------------------------------
 This only 1 line too   | This guy might go all the
                        | way onto 3 lines if I mak
                        | e him long enough
====================================================
```

For reference, `OutputFormatter._outputMaxLength` is the width of the table, i.e. the length of `====================================================`, and `PrintChars('=')` is what prints that.

Comment: There are many ways, you can take a look at for example this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1450797/3110834) or this [one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3008775/3110834)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use `String.Take(numOfChars)` for it:

```
string line;
var numOfChars = 30;
var input = "Quite long text to break into 30 characters";
while ((line = new String(input.Take(numOfChars).ToArray())).Any())
{
    Console.WriteLine(line);
    input = new String(input.Skip(numOfChars).ToArray());
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use *Linq*:

```
  int size = 4; // 30 in your case
  String sample = "ABCDEFGHI";

  var chunks = Enumerable
    .Range(0, sample.Length / size + (sample.Length / size == 0 ? 0 : 1))
    .Select(i => sample.Substring(i * size, Math.Min(size, sample.Length - i * size)));
```

Test

```
   // ABCD
   // EFGH
   // I
   Console.Write(String.Join(Environment.NewLine, chunks));
```

Comment: Maybe the second `/` should be `%` in the argument to `Range`?